# Pattern to abstract simple code to work on multiple records by using Custom Settings

Tags: apex, customsetting

**Background:** I want to add all users who are assigned a specific permission set to a specific chatter group.  I have a simple version of this working, but would like to abstract this to use a list custom setting to store ChatterGroupName and PermissionSetName so I can run this on N pairings, and then make it scheduleable and perhaps batchable tho I dont think the data volume will need to go batchable.

**Question:** I cant wrap my head around a pattern to use in moving from my little proof of concept that has one method to handle one permission set / chatter group, to one that works w N number of records from a custom setting.

**Where I'm at:** I created a simple class and called it via execute anonymous and amazingly enough users were added to the chatter group as desired. I have created a custom setting and added 2 records in it, and i added a line to my controller to populate a list with the rows from it.  And...now I dont really know what to do next, besides for coming up with a more concise name for the custom setting.

I feel like I could wrap the whole thing in a giant `for` loop, but that just seems wrong.  My sense is that I need to use maps, but I dont really have the experience w/ maps needed to think through how to proceed, so requesting some top-level help on how best to do so. Also would appreciate any tips / flags for things to look out for that might blow up now or when I try to go scheduleable.

**Controller Code:**

```
public class UserAddToChatterGroupFromPermSet {
    list <Permission_Set_Chatter_Group_Map__c> pscg = new list <Permission_Set_Chatter_Group_Map__c> ([SELECT Permission_Set_Name__c, Chatter_Group_Name__c FROM Permission_Set_Chatter_Group_Map__c WHERE Active__c = TRUE]);
    list <user> psusers = new list<user>();
    list <permissionsetassignment> psa = new list <permissionsetassignment>();
    permissionset permset = new permissionset();
    collaborationgroup cg = new collaborationgroup();
    set <Id> permSetUserIds = new set<Id>();
    set <Id> cgUserIds = new set<Id>();


    public UserAddToChatterGroupFromPermSet(){
        addUsersToEchosignGroup();
    }

    public void addUsersToEchosignGroup() {

        //get all active users currently assigned permission set
        permset = [SELECT Id from PermissionSet WHERE Label = 'App: Echosign' LIMIT 1];
        system.debug('permset id = ' + permset);
        psusers = [SELECT Name, ID from USER WHERE ID IN (SELECT AssigneeID from PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSetId =: permset.Id) AND IsActive = TRUE];
        system.debug('users = ' + psusers);

        //get all group members currently in chatter group
        cg = [SELECT ID from CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = 'E-Signature Users (Adobe Echosign)'];
        list <CollaborationGroupMember> cgusers = new list <CollaborationGroupMember>([SELECT MemberId from CollaborationGroupMember WHERE CollaborationGroupId =: cg.Id ]);
        system.debug('cgusers = ' + cgusers);

        //compare existing perm set users ID to collaboration group members ID and prepare list of cgmembers to insert
        FOR(CollaborationGroupMember cguser : cgusers){
            cguserIds.add(cguser.MemberId);
        }
        list <CollaborationGroupMember> cgUsersToInsert = new list <CollaborationGroupMember>();
        FOR(User psuser : psusers){
            CollaborationGroupMember cgmember = new CollaborationGroupMember();
            IF(cguserIds.contains(psuser.Id)){
                }
            ELSE{
                cgmember.MemberId = psuser.Id;
                cgmember.CollaborationGroupId = cg.Id;
                cgusersToInsert.add(cgmember);
            }
        }
        system.debug('cgUsersToInsertsize = ' + cgusersToInsert.size());
        IF(cgUsersToInsert.size() >= 1){
        insert(cgUsersToInsert);
        }
        ELSE{
            system.debug('no cg members to insert');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Common Misconceptions

You do not need to check if a collection of records is empty before performing `DML` on it. Check the following in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
insert new List<Lead>();
system.assertEquals(0, Limits.getDMLStatements());
```

So there is no need to check if `cgUsersToInsert.isEmpty()` before calling `insert`.

Also, you do not need to do `new List<SObject>([query])`. Just replace any instance of that with `[query]`. In addition to being less verbose, it probably consumes less CPU Time.

### Answer

You should make your query by a unique field. In this case, I would use `PermissionSet.Name` instead of `PermissionSet.Label`. `CollaborationGroup.Name` is fine, since it is unique. You can use a `List Custom Setting` with fields for these two values. I would just name them `PermissionSet__c` and `CollaborationGroup__c`.

#### Step 1: Get Filter Data

You need to get a `Set<String>` for each `WHERE` filter:

```
Set<String> permissionSetNames = new Set<String>();
Set<String> chatterGroupNames = new Set<String>();
for (PermissionSet_ChatterGroup__c mapping : PermissionSet_ChatterGroup__c)
{
    permissionSetNames.add(mapping.PermissionSet__c);
    chatterGroupNames.add(mapping.CollaborationGroup__c);
}
```

#### Step 2: Query SObject Data

```
List<PermissionSet> permissionSets = new List<PermissionSet>();
for (PermissionSet permissionSet : [
    SELECT Name, (SELECT AssigneeId FROM Assignments)
    FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name IN :permissionSetNames
]) permissionSets.add(permissionSet);

Map<String, CollaborationGroup> chatterGroups = new Map<String, CollaborationGroup>();
for (CollaborationGroup chatterGroup : [
    SELECT Name FROM CollaborationGroup
    WHERE Name IN :chatterGroupNames
]) chatterGroups.put(chatterGroup.Name, chatterGroup);
```

#### Step 3: Tie Into Existing Code

I think you should be able to figure most of the remaining steps out. Change your `User` query sub-filter from `PermissionSetId =: permset.Id` to `PermissionSet.Name IN :permissionSets.keySet()`. Your `CollaborationGroupMember` filter will need a similar modification.

You can loop through the child `PermissionSetAssignment` records as follows:

```
for (PermissionSet permissionSet : permissionSets)
{
    for (PermissionSetAssignment assignment : permissionSet.Assignments)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Slick, eh? If you're curious how I got the name of this child relationship:

```
DescribeSObjectResult describe = SObjectType.PermissionSet;
for (ChildRelationship relationship : describe.getChildRelationships())
{
    if (relationship.getChildSObject() == PermissionSetAssignment.SObjectType)
        system.debug(relationship.getRelationshipName());
}
```

Comment: it never crossed my mind that it would be possible to store the child Assignee Ids 'inside' a PermissionSet sObject from a single query.   This is very cool.  I am trying to figure out how to access these child IDs when I retrieve a permissionSet 'ps' from the map.  i've tried dot notation ps.Assignments.AssigneeId and a for loop (which seems wierd since its a single perm set) but neither is compiling - can you clue me in to how to get at these?  Trying to add them to a set of IDs.  Thanks

Comment: finally got it...ps.Assignments gets me the list of child permssionSetAssignment sObjects...

Comment: @gorav See my updated answer. :)

Comment: thanks @adrian I just used the same technique to pull in collaboration group members in the collaboration group query.  I am slowly slashing and burning my way towards a solution, turning back when i get into nested for loops and i think w a few more attempts i will finally get a sense of proper use of maps!

Comment: @gorav good luck man, you got this!

Comment: the beagle has landed.  this is most awesome.  used a set to store the collaborationgroupmembers so it can handle multiple perm sets to a single group and vice versa.  prob will take me a month to write the tests for this, but then i think it might be time to join the github.  i know comments aren't for saying thanks, but thanks anyways! the updated version is at http://pastebin.com/x8n2EDUJ it has more for loops than I would like but no queries inside of them so i think fundamentally ok.

Comment: Glad I could help. :) You don't seem to have any queries or dml in your loops so you're good there. One recommendation to make testing easier, break out all these little chunks into helper functions you can test directly. @gorav